# How to show all questions [dwqa-list-questions] for admin (wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, nlp-question-answering

I'm using a dwqa plugin.
[dwqa-list-questions] only shows questions that the author wrote.
Admin can only see questions that an admin wrote.
I need to show all the questions for admin.
Would you please let me know how to implement it?

Thank you.

Comment: Ask the plugin support - they made it, they will know: https://www.designwall.com/question/dwqa-plugin/

Comment: Hi Fresz: Thank you for your adivce. I actually asked this quation, and it showed Your question is waiting moderator, then no reply... So.. I'm asking here just in case someone know the method...